# apache tomcat redirect request between servlets

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet, lets call it ServletA which is the default servlet. 
I also have ServletB which listen on URL /blabla/*.
Let say I have an HTTP get request for my server `https://myServer/devices/devicesName`
It will first go to ServletA  (as expected). Now I want to redirect it to servletB `https://myServer/blabla/devicesName`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

To redirect from ServletA to your ServletB just write:

```
response.sendRedirect("https://myServer/blabla/devicesName");
```

in your ServletA doGet() method. Since your ServletB is mapped to `https://myServer/blabla/devicesName` it will handle the request.

Note that a redirect creates new request. Since it is a new request, the old request and response objects are lost.